# Error not the right calcul result PHP

Tags: php

I want to calculate a rate value and i don't have the right result.

Everything works except the rate value

Can anybody help me to find the problem with my code.

This's my query :

```
   $sql = "

       SELECT

         check_code.codegroup,
         check.check_1,
         check.check_2,
         check.check_3,
         COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN check_product.product ELSE 0 END) as checkproduct

      FROM check_code.code_group

      LEFT JOIN check_product ON check_product.codegroup = check_code.codegroup
      LEFT JOIN check ON check_product.codegroup = check.code_group

      GROUP BY check_code.id_code_group
      ORDER BY check_code.id_code_group DESC

      ";

        <td>codegroup</td>
        <td>checkproduct</td>
        <td>check_1</td>
        <td>check_2</td>
        <td>check_3</td>
        <td>Rate</td>

        <?php   

          foreach ( $data as $query => $a ) :

          //to calcule rate
           $rate = ($a["check_1"] * 0.15) + ($a["check_2"] * 0.35) + ($a["check_3"] * 0.5) * 100 /$a["checkproduct"];


         <td><? echo $a["codegroup"];?></td>

         <td><? if($a["checkproduct"]==1){}else{echo $a["checkproduct"];}?></td>

                    <td><? echo $a["check_1"];?></td>
                    <td><? echo $a["check_2"];?></td>
                    <td><? echo $a["check_3"];?></td>
                    <td><? echo $rate;?></td>
```

Example :

```
This what my code return  : 

  codegroup |checkproduct|check_1|check_2|check_3|rate
  AL16bof05      94        1       1       1      1.031914893617
```

And this's what i want to return :

```
   codegroup| checkproduct|check_1|check_2|check_3|rate
    AL16bof05      94        1       1       1      1.06338297
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the 'false result'? Please give some more info...

Comment: I have a false result with my rate value.

Comment: You do realise that `false` has a very specific meaning in programmig languages, related to boolean values

Comment: However, what result are you expecting to see?

Comment: @MarkBaker I add an example with what i return with my code and what i want to return

Comment: That was what we needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic math error. In details its about [operators precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

> Multiplication has precedence over (which means *happens before*)  sum.

You have *sum of 3  multiplication/division expressions*:

```
$rate = ($a["check_1"] * 0.15) 
      + ($a["check_2"] * 0.35) 
      + ($a["check_3"] * 0.5) * 100 /$a["checkproduct"];
```

While you want to calulate sum first and then mupltiply it by `100 /$a["checkproduct"]`

So you have to put brackets around sum:

```
$rate = ( ($a["check_1"] * 0.15) + ($a["check_2"] * 0.35) + ($a["check_3"] * 0.5) ) 
        * 100 /$a["checkproduct"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some brackets `()` to correclty interprete the [Operator Precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). This is basic Math and has nothing do to with 'coding'.

```
$rate = ($a["check_1"] * 0.15) + ($a["check_2"] * 0.35) + ($a["check_3"] * 0.5) * 100 /$a["checkproduct"];
```

This produces `1,031914894`

Should become:

```
$rate = (($a["check_1"] * 0.15) + ($a["check_2"] * 0.35) + ($a["check_3"] * 0.5)) * 100 /$a["checkproduct"];
```

This produces `1,063829787`

Please note the extra brackets

Comment: Thank so much  for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a parenthesis, therefore the order of the operations is wrong, giving you the wrong result

```
$rate = ($a["check_1"] * 0.15) + ($a["check_2"] * 0.35) + ($a["check_3"] * 0.5)) * 100 /$a["checkproduct"];
                                                                               ^
```

This will basically do a `1 * 100/94`, meaning `1,063829787234043`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.